# TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to use values from a dataframe in functions like `range` or compare the values to non-dataframe values? My code is:

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Qty': [20,34,12,43]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand','Qty'], index=['1','2','3','4'])


nr_of_cars = 0
rng = range(0, df['Qty'], 1)
for i in rng:
    nr_of_cars =+ 1


qty15 = 0
if df['Qty'] > 15:
    qty15 =+ 0

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not for sure what's your point.
But if you want to get a DataFrame where 'Qty' > 15, you can do it like this:

```
df[df['Qty'] > 15]
```

Or you may want this:

```
[item for item in df['Qty'] if item > 15]
```

It returns a list with elements which great than 15.